# USACO Contest New Rules with Standard Input and Output

Tags: python, input, output

so I was preparing to take this year's USACO test, but noticed that there was a new rule in the about saying "As an important change from last year, ALL SUBMISSIONS NOW USE STANDARD INPUT AND OUTPUT (e.g., cin and cout in C++) instead of file input and output. You therefore no longer need to open files to read your input or write your output. As another note, participants are advised to re-read the contest rules, as we have clarified some of the key contest regulations (in particular, that use of any previously-written code or code from external sources is NOT allowed)." What does the Standard input and output mean? How would that work for python? Does that mean that you don't read in data from files and write them into other files?

Comment: `input` and `print` instead of `open(...).read()` and `open(...).write()`

Comment: You can also use `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` and access them like files.

Answer (score 0):

`input()` and `print()` should suffice. It worked when I tried to do a USACO problem in python a while back.

If you want to read the input like a file, you can use `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout`, but I find that it is unnecessary and probably just extra work.